# Failed to create configuration database during installation

Tags: configuration-wizard

I am stuck with sharepoint foundation 2010 configuration.
The error is:

> Failed to create configuration database, An exception of
>   system.io.filenotfoundexception was thrown

This is the log entry

> 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                Leaving function
>   Command.this[string key] 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   The parameter password is NOT chosen, the default value as null
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                Entering function
>   Command.this[string key] 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6 
>   INF                    Found value in collection for key passphrase
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                  Leaving function
>   CommandCollectionBase.Get 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Found parameter passphrase in collection 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Leaving function Command.this[string key] 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF 
>   The parameter passphrase is NOT chosen, the default value as null
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                Entering function
>   Farm.IsJoinedToFarm 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Entering function Farm.TryIsJoinedToFarm 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key] 07/23/2013
>   15:58:20  6  INF                      Entering function
>   CommandCollectionBase.Get 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Found value in collection for key initialize 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6 
>   INF                      Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                      Found command
>   initialize in collection 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key] 07/23/2013
>   15:58:20  6  INF                    Entering function
>   Command.this[string key] 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6 
>   INF                        Found value in collection for key
>   B2B_UPGRADE 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                      Leaving
>   function CommandCollectionBase.Get 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Found parameter B2B_UPGRADE in collection 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF 
>   Leaving function Command.this[string key] 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF 
>   My cached Farm object is null, so will load it 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6 
>   INF                    Calling SPFarm.Local and SPServer.Local to get
>   the local farm objects 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   SPFarm.Local returned null.  This usually means that the server is not
>   joined.  But, you can delete a server from the configdb without
>   unjoining, which would mean that this machine still thinks it is
>   joined. 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                    Trying to
>   access the server farm connection string 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Entering function TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                      Entering function
>   RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   The RegistryHelper has the key name as Software\Microsoft\Shared
>   Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB and the registry hive
>   as LocalMachine 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Leaving function RegistryHelper.RegistryHelper 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6 
>   INF                      Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 registry
>   key Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
>   Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB for the connection string does not
>   exist 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                      Unable to get
>   the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 connection string 07/23/2013
>   15:58:20  6  INF                    Leaving function
>   TaskCommon.TryGetWssVersion4ConnectionStringExists 07/23/2013 15:58:20
>   6  INF                    DID NOT discover a v4 connection string and
>   SPFarm.Local indicates that this machine is not joined. 07/23/2013
>   15:58:20  6  INF                    Entering function Farm.Clear
>   07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF                      Entering function
>   CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Leaving function CentralAdminServiceInstance.Reset 07/23/2013 15:58:20
>   6  INF                    Leaving function Farm.Clear 07/23/2013
>   15:58:20  6  INF                  Leaving function
>   Farm.TryIsJoinedToFarm 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Leaving function Farm.IsJoinedToFarm 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Creating connection string for config db
>   SharePoint_Config_d459b728-3ec9-45a8-95b8-d9ed0cca6df2 server
>   CLBBLR-6240\Sharepoint 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Creating connection string for admin content db
>   SharePoint_AdminContent_5616403b-4ffc-4e74-a574-ea8d5a851607 server
>   CLBBLR-6240\Sharepoint 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Using NTLM for sql connection string 07/23/2013 15:58:20  6  INF
>   Creating a new farm with config db
>   SharePoint_Config_d459b728-3ec9-45a8-95b8-d9ed0cca6df2 content db
>   SharePoint_AdminContent_5616403b-4ffc-4e74-a574-ea8d5a851607 server
>   CLBBLR-6240\Sharepoint for eval mode 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  1  INF                Not
>   running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 15:58:20  107/23/2013 16:53:09  1  INF
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in
>   high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked
>   image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast,
>   so we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:51  1  INF        Old location for the navigation panel is
>   {X=-264,Y=-39}, new location is {X=351,Y=466} 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1 
>   INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the
>   background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in
>   high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked
>   image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast,
>   so we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint
>   the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF 
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in
>   high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked
>   image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast,
>   so we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint
>   the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF 
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in
>   high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked
>   image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast,
>   so we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint
>   the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF 
>   Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:51  1  INF        Not running in
>   high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked
>   image 07/23/2013 16:54:53  1  INF        Not running in high contrast,
>   so we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:53  1  INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint
>   the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013 16:54:53  1  INF 
>   Entering function PsconfigLinkLabel.LinkLabelClickedEventHandler
>   07/23/2013 16:54:53  1  INF          Clicking the link data C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_7_23_2013_15_57_22_699_1523409182.log
>   07/23/2013 16:54:53  1  INF          Not running in high contrast, so
>   we will paint the background with our trademarked image 07/23/2013
>   16:54:53  1  INF        Leaving function
>   PsconfigLinkLabel.LinkLabelClickedEventHandler 07/23/2013 16:54:53  1 
>   INF        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the
>   background with our trademarked image

Comment: The root cause is usually mentioned in a setup log file. Could you provide some more context? Probably a SQL connection or permissions error.

Comment: I am installing it in my windows 7 machine

Comment: Have you checked for the Password strength.

Comment: Password strength of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here :

http://shareatsharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html#!/2012/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html

Now it works

Comment: The above link does not exist anymore. Any alternate link will be beneficial.